# Method not executing inside another method using Vue.js event

Tags: vuejs2

I'm learning how to use vue.js to pull movie information and display it.

Inside the main application mc I have a method getMovie which isn't being called when another method updateMovie is called.  The updateMovie method is called from the event 'switch' which is emitted by a child component details-card

I can see that the title on my application gets changed and the method updateMovie is working if you click on a director and then a movie under that director.  The input field also changes value.  Why won't the getMovie work?

```js
var mc = new Vue({
  el: "#movie-card",
  data: {
    title: '',
    valid: false,
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    mc: {},
    directorArray: [],
    actorArray: [],
  },
  computed: {
    checkMulti: function(item) {
      if (Object.keys(item).length <= 1) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getMovie: function() {
      this.cm = {};
      console.log("getMovie called")

      if (this.title !== "") {
        this.loading = true;
        this.error = false;
        searchString = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + this.title;
        var that = this;
        axios.get(searchString)
          .then(function(res) {
            that.cm = res.data;
            that.directorArray = res.data.Director.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
            that.actorArray = res.data.Actors.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
            that.valid = true;
            that.loading = false;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            that.loading = false;
            that.error = true;
          })
      }
    },
    updateMovie: function(movie) {
      console.log(movie);
      this.title = movie;
      this.getMovie;
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('details-card', {
  props: [
    'name', 
    'title'
  ],
  template: `

<div>
  <a href="" 
    @click="handleShowDetails($event)"
    >
      {{ name }}
  </a>
  <div v-if="visible" class="detailsCard">
    <h3 class="removeTopMargin">{{ name }}</h3>
    <img :src="picUrl">
    <h4>Known for</h4>
    <p v-for="movie in knownForArray">
      <a href="" 
        @click="switchMovie(movie.original_title, $event)"
        >{{ movie.original_title }}</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      picUrl: "",
      knownForArray: [],
      visible: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleShowDetails: function($event) {
      this.visible = !this.visible;
      this.callPic($event);
    },
    switchMovie( movie , $event) {
      if ($event) $event.preventDefault();
      console.log("switching to...", movie);
      this.$emit('switch', movie);
    },
    callPic: function(event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      let that = this;
      let searchString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=9b8f2bdd1eaf20c57554e6d25e0823a2&language=en-US&query=" + this.name + "&page=1&include_adult=false";
      if (!this.picUrl) { //only load if empty
        axios.get(searchString)
          .then(function(res) {
            let profilePath = res.data.results[0].profile_path;
            if (profilePath === null) {
              that.picUrl = "http://placehold.it/150x200"
            } else {
              that.picUrl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w150/' + profilePath;
            }
            that.personPic = profilePath;
          
            that.knownForArray = res.data.results[0].known_for;
        }).catch(function(err){
          console.log(err);
        })
      }
    },
    hideDetails: function () {
      this.visible= false;
    }
  }
    
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.loading {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 450px;
}
.details {
  display:block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
}



.searchBar {
  padding: .5em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  text-align: center;
}

.searchBar input {
  padding: .5em;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.searchBar button {
  padding: .2em;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:#333;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: .33em;
}

.card {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  padding: 2em;
}

.detailsCard {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px 2px rgba(168,168,168,0.45);
  padding: 1em;
}




/* ======= Typography  */
html {font-size: 1em;}

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: #333;
}

p {margin-bottom: 1.3em;}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  margin: 1.414em 0 0.5em;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
h2, h3, h4 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3.998em;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {font-size: 2.827em;}

h3 {font-size: 1.999em;}

h4 {font-size: 1.414em;}

small, .font_small {font-size: 0.707em;}

.removeTopMargin {
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>


<div id="movie-card">
  <div class="searchBar">
    <input type="text" ref="input" v-model="title" placeholder="Enter a movie title here..." v-on:keyup.enter="getMovie">
    <button type="submit" @click="getMovie">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="loading" v-if="loading">
    <BR><BR>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="loading" v-if="error">
    <BR><BR>
    <h1>Something went wrong!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card" v-if="valid && !loading">
    <h1> {{ cm.Title }}</h1>
    <div v-if="!(cm.Poster === 'N/A')" class="poster">
      <img v-bind:src="cm.Poster">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>{{ cm.Year + " &ndash; " + cm.Rated + " &ndash; " + cm.Runtime }}</p>
    </div>
    <p>{{ cm.Plot }}</p>

    <div class="directors" v-if="cm.Director">
      <h3 v-if="(directorArray.length > 1)">Director</h3>
      <h3 v-else>Director</h3>
      <p>
        <p v-for="(director, index) in directorArray">
          <details-card :name="director" v-on:switch="updateMovie"></details-card>
        </p>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="actors" v-if="cm.Actors">
      <h3 v-if="actorArray.length > 1">Actors</h3>
      <h3 v-else>Actor</h3>
      <p>
        <p v-for="(actor, index) in actorArray">
          <details-card :name="actor"></details-card>
        </p>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="ratings" v-if="cm.Ratings">
      <h3>Ratings</h3>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="rating in cm.Ratings">{{ rating.Source }}: {{ rating.Value }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you didnt call it? `this.getMovie;`

Comment: I call it inside the updateMovie method

Comment: what I see is `updateMovie: function(movie) {
      console.log(movie);
      this.title = movie;
      this.getMovie;
    }` there is no invocation for `this.getMovie`

Comment: Got it... I can't believe I didn't do `this.getMovie()`   Thank you